# Power BI conditional formatting based on percentiles

Tags: powerbi, dax, conditional-formatting

Is there a way in Power BI to apply conditional formatting based on percentiles? It is very useful feature if the data contains outlier observations.

In Excel I have been used to easily make it:
[image]

I know I can make formatting based on whatever **field** which can be a measure.

I wanted to construct a DAX measure:

```
Sales_per_category_percentile = PERCENTILE.EXC(DISTINCT(table[Category]) , [Sales]))
```

But it does not accept `DISTINCT(table[Category])` as the first argument of the `PERCENTILE.EXC` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do conditional formatting on a Matrix.

Just got released on the [power-bi-desktop-july-2019](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-july-2019-feature-summary/#percentRules)

> In addition to adding a new type of conditional formatting, we’ve
>   extended in general our Rules form of conditional formatting to
>   support Percent, which allows you to apply formatting on a dynamic
>   range of data, instead of having to specify an absolute number that
>   can become absolute as data refreshes. We also added the Reverse
>   button from the Icon dialog for colors as well, so it’s easier to
>   quick swap the direction of your rules.

[image: Percent option]

Let's look at the PERCENTILE.EXC definition.

```
PERCENTILE.EXC(<column>, <k>)

Term    Definition
column  A column containing the values that define relative standing.
k       The percentile value in the range 0..1, exclusive.
```

EDIT:(you are correct VALUES does not work)
You have to supply a column. And choose your K between 0 and 1 exclusive, let's say 0.5

```
Sales_per_category_percentile = PERCENTILE.EXC('Fact'[Salesamount],0.5)
```

And use it in a Matrix with your table[Category] in Rows for example.

[image]

EDIT2: For binning and grouping have a look at:
[Grouping and Binning in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/power-bi/desktop-grouping-and-binning)

Comment: Thanks for bringing the new July 2019 update feature. Great! However your suggestion on percentile measure does not work. VALUES wouldn't help. I do not know why. Usually DISTINCT or VALUES servers as making tables.

Comment: I noticed I need something opposite to Percentile function. I want to know in which Percentile the observation is. In other words, I want to know in which of the 100 buckets is my particular observation. The Percentile functions calculates ONE value for specific percentile.